# Gedit not displaying certain tabs

Tags: 12.04, gedit

I am using gedit to edit a ruby file. In `gedit` (and `Sublime`) certain tabs are not displayed, that are displayed when I paste into the Internet, open with `vi` or open with `Geany`.

This is all summarized in the following photo which you can zoom in to see the details (look at the lines that start with a `#`:
[image: Examples of tabs not displaying]

Is this a setting problem or an actual bug that I should report? This would be a minor problem except unexpected tabs break my documentation generator, which breaks more things that are important to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a hidden character problem. I was using a mix of tabs and spaces that wasn't being detected by `gedit`, but was being displayed by `vi` since it had a different tab size. Converting all of my spaces into tabs fixed the problem.